# Woocommerce cart session expiration

Tags: wordpress, session, woocommerce, cart

How to clear Woocommerce cart after x amount of time. I need to reset the session after 30 minutes (Use case: cart was abandoned).

Tried using Woocommerce Cart Expiration plugin but it does not work for last version of Woocommerce 5.7.1 [Woocommerce cart expiration](https://github.com/liquidweb/woo-cart-expiration).

Also tried via filter (pasted in functions.php), but it doesn't do the job :

```
add_filter('wc_session_expiring', 'so_26545001_filter_session_expiring' );

function so_26545001_filter_session_expiring($seconds) {
    return 60 * 25; // 25 mins
}

add_filter('wc_session_expiration', 'so_26545001_filter_session_expired' );

function so_26545001_filter_session_expired($seconds) {
    return 60 * 30; // 30 mins
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this -

```
// Start session if not started
add_action('init', 'register_my_session');
function register_my_session(){
   if( !session_id() ) {
      session_start();
   }
}

// Clear cart after 30 minutes
add_action( 'init', 'woocommerce_clear_cart' );
function woocommerce_clear_cart() 
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $current_time = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $expiry_in_seconds = 1800; // 30 minutes

    if (!isset($_SESSION['active_time'])) 
    {
        $_SESSION['active_time'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
    else{
        // add 30 minutes
        $cart_expiry_time = strtotime($_SESSION['active_time']) + $expiry_in_seconds;
        // calculate seconds left
        $diff = $cart_expiry_time - strtotime($current_time);

        // round to minutes
        $remaining_minutes = floor($diff/60);

        // if time less than or equal to 1 minutes
        if($remaining_minutes<=1)
        {
            //if (isset($_GET['clear-cart']) && $_GET['clear-cart'] == 1) 
             {
                $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
                //WC()->session->set('cart', array());
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Best Method: You should set up a cron job and run accordingly like every 10 minutes. if you want the same function for cronjob kindly uncomment if condition and increase the remaining time like this:

```
if($remaining_minutes<=15){
     if (isset($_GET['clear-cart']) && $_GET['clear-cart'] == 1) {
          $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
          //WC()->session->set('cart', array());
     }
}
```

and add URL on cronejon like this:

https://example.com?clear-cart=1 // your full site domain with param ?clear-cart=1

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I added two products into the cart 30+minutes ago (both when logged in and logged out -incognito) and now they are gone from the cart. Awesome. If the snippet above works should i still add the cronjob ?

Comment: Yes for auto-delete after 30 min - need to cronjob